# Android open folder image with built-in gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I want to open a images folder with android built-in gallery.
For example, I have a folder path that contains images, i want to open it with gallery.
I am using this code, it opens the gallery that contains no images.
Any idea?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new  File(folderImages)),"image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: I assume you copy & pasted incorrectly and your code sample is actually: `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new  File(folderImages)),"image/*");`

Comment: Try using "image/jpg" instead of the wildcard in that case.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(4468): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/BWPP typ=image/jpg }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6543/discussion-between-michel-foucault-and-jens)

Comment: Did you find answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 1)
```